# Get hostname and pid in scala without using java classes?

Tags: scala

Is there a better/more idiomatic/less jvm reliant way of grabbing a host/pid than using java libs such as ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean.getName?

Just wondering what the preferred way in scala is?

Comment: If it ain't broke don't fix it, so why not just stick with that since it works?  I don't think the scala runtime provides anything better out of the box for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run on the JVM, as Scala does, you're JVM-reliant.  The Java libs are the canonical way to interact with the JVM to fetch such information, so you should use them.  Scala does not provide an alternative, and any alternative that was provided would likely be less reliable as Typesafe does not have the resources that Sun/Oracle/IBM/etc. did/does.  It does mean that if you use an experimental or hobby-level JVM that you may be out of luck getting your host name.  (You can always spawn an external process and use a Linux command-line utility, if your JVM supports that, of course, but don't expect that to be terribly portable.)

Comment: Alright. I like to check now as doing things the java way is generally considered "wrong" on scala despite the reliance on the jvm and interoperability.

Comment: @JasonG - The Java way is not considered "wrong" _just because_ it is how Java does things.  Rather, in the time since Java has been created, people have realized that there are better ways to do a number of things.  But there are various low level capabilities (esp. including JVM monitoring) where there can be no more canonical way to do it than the Java way (e.g. there may be no other way because you need machine code and the Java library is what has it).  Doing things the Java way when there's a superior way in Scala is what's considered wrong.  (But how would you know except by asking?)

Comment: Thanks for your time - hence the question :)